# Setting up network, access via LAN or modem

Tags: networking

I'm trying to do something unusual (for me; I'm barely a networking power user). I have a modem that has a static IP address assigned from Verizon. It's connected to a switch. I also have two PCs connected to that switch.  The modem is configured to do port forwarding to a web server running on one PC.  I'd like to be able to connect to that web server either on the LAN (using the second PC) or from the greater internet through the modem. The LAN access is fine, but the modem access doesn't work. I think I've double-checked everything, and all of the IP addresses are okay. Is there any reason why a setup like this wouldn't work?  Thanks!

ETA: I'm sure I'm missing some details here, but for one, everything has a static IP address.  The LAN addresses are 192.168.40.x.

Comment: Can you describe the hardware you are using and the exact service you have from Verizon?

Comment: i would recheck port forwarding. you're not getting through the router/modem. Port 80, 443, both? Does the router/modem log anything?

Comment: The modem is made by Motorola. It has worked in this capacity before.  I can ping the modem.  It's a static IP address from Verizon.

Comment: The modem doesn't log much, unfortunately. I figured that that's where the problem is, but it seems fine. I'll triple-check it. (Port 8000, by the way; web server on an unusual port.)  Sounds like there's nothing inherently crazy about what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you can find the clear road map how the traffic will be routed when you browse your website.
Check the main factors in given order which is responsible for website hosting

1.Domain propagation.
2.Public IP address.
3.Your Router port forwarding.
4.Web server Firewall (local machine).
5.Local machine (DNS i.e - host configuration).
6.Web content (Create a test page and check)

Note : It seems to be issue with your port forwarding and domain propagation (if you using with domain name)

Road map:
{((Internet ))} <---- -- -- -- --> | Modem (Static IP address i.e - Public IP)| <-------> | Web Server ( Local IP address)

Thanks,